# Ubuntu 18.04.4 Bionic does not run any newly installed application

Tags: lubuntu

I am trying to install Opera browser or Chrome or any other available application on Linux.
The installation is clean and no error is thrown. However upon clicking on the application the cursor shows spinning around and after a few seconds nothing happens.

Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64) is written at the top of my command prompt.

Comment: How are you installing them? Try starting them from the terminal and the output may give you helpful information about resolving this issue.

Comment: I have tried terminal and also the software module. From terminal I can install them the same way no error is given. From the software module I get /tmp/sanity-mountpoint operation not permitted SNAPd issues which I do not believe that are related and if they are I have no idea how to fix or configure it as well.

Comment: What command did you enter into the terminal to install your app? (Add that info to your question by editing it.) After you install your app, try to run it in the terminal by typing the app name. Share that information by adding it to your question. For example, in the terminal, `sudo apt install audacity` (follow the prompts) and then in the same terminal window type `audacity` and see if it starts.

Comment: I do a simple apt-get or curl command to download. the command does not run and no action is taken. As if it is not even entered.

Comment: Providing your actual commands (exactly), and output will help us understand your issue. To get the actual command if done at terminal, you'll find it in your command `history`, for GUI apps you'll need to look in logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log` for apt|deb|dpkg installs).  Please add additional detail to your question (greater formatting options exist, making it easier to read). How much disk space exists in your installation?  Do you have the recommended minimum of 25GB or less?  What RAM do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out adding this comment solved the issue

```
sed -i -e 's@Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U@Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --no-sandbox@g' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```